# Error with Grails 2.4 in Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: grails, weblogic, sitemesh

I've run across a problem with Grails 2.4 war running in Weblogic 10.3.6 that seems to be coming from Sitemesh:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SitemeshLayoutView.createContentBufferingResponse(SitemeshLayoutView.java:40)
```

So the question would be is there a known requirement on servlet version 3.0 to run Grails 2.4?  I see nothing in the documentation that says that, and actually find the opposite here:
http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/gettingStarted.html#supportedJavaEEContainers

Comment: What's your container compliance set to in BuildConfig.groovy? grails.servlet.version is the key for this setting.

Comment: grails.servlet.version = "2.5" in build config, app.servlet.version=2.5 in application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GRAILS-11450](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11450) - According to this JIRA it looks like Grails 2.4 is Servlet 3.0 and above, which means the documentation is incorrect.

EDIT:
Grails 2.4.1 has restored Servlet 2.5 support